# Assign the result of Navigation Property to View Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, viewmodel, code-first

Here is my database schema:-

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee_Id { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Salary { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department_Id { get; set; }
}
```

According to my research its a good practice to use **View Models** so I usually create my model with this kind of queries:-

```
var v = edm.Departments.Select(x => new departmentViewModel { Name = x.Name });
return v.ToList();
```

Now I like to add the benefit of **Navigation Property** into my code. Problem is its not useful for me if I cant assign the result to my **View Model**. If I try to access to a *Department* through a *Employee* I cant access to **.Select()** statement.

```
var v = edm.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault().Department_Id. //Ops!!!
```

In above statement I can access to `Id` and `Name` but `.Select()` is inaccessible.

I can ignore **Navigation Property** and break my query into two queries and achieve what I want. But I'm asking how am I be able to to this with **Navigation Property**? Am I just misunderstanding the usage of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in fact in my schema there is no **Navigation Property**. To have a *Navigation Property* you must have **Constructor** in your classes and **ForeignKey** that refer to that constructor.

```
public class Department
{
    public Department(){} //needed constructor

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int Employee_Id;
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Employee(){} //needed constructor

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Salary { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int Department_Id;
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can access to *Department* through *Employee* in a standard way but **.Select()** statement is still inaccessible. That doesn't really matter, I found that I can copy the result into **View Model** in next line without *.Select()* statement.

```
var e = edm.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault().Department; //.select() is still inaccessible
departmentViewModel department = new departmentViewModel() { Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name };//but I could copy the result into my View Model here
```